# Which program will be bigger in size - RISC or CISC?

Tags: risc

Let's say I have a hello world program, which print 'Hello World'. 
Now, I have compiled this program for CISC Processor and next I have compiled for RISC processor. My question is which will have bigger code size and why?

Answer (score 0):

The programs will be the same size. As both of them consist simply of passing a string constant to a system call.

Comment: But in general, which program will be of bigger size CISC or RISC?